# Dynamic PlotLine in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a scatter plot with a horizontal PlotLine.  I would like people to be able to drag the PlotLine.  The y axis value is used as a threshold value to generate a column chart (the column chart is initially generated with a default value for the threshold).  So far I have the draggable plotline working using code that I found on the Highcharts forum:

```
var line,
    clickX,
    clickY;

var start= function (e) {
    $(document).bind({
        'mousemove.line': step,
        'mouseup.line': stop
    });
    clickY=e.pageY - line.translateY;
}

var step = function (e) {
    line.translate(e.pageX - clickX, e.pageY - clickY)
}

var stop = function (e) {
    var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
    var max_y_axis = chart.yAxis[0].max;
    var newVal = chart.yAxis[0].toValue(e.pageY - clickY + chart.plotTop) + chart.yAxis[0].plotLinesAndBands[0].options.value)- max_y_axis;
    $('#report').text('Value: ' + newVal);
    $(document).unbind('.line');
}
```

This works fine and I can see that the threshold value is being produced correctly.  However, I would like to access the value newVal (the threshold) elsewhere in my code, i.e. to create the 2nd chart.  Does anyone have an idea of how I can get newVal outside of the function?

Comment: It is possible to recreate entire chart which shows us that newVal is not defined /  availbe when you create new one?

Comment: newVal is available within the function that defines var stop.  But not available outside the function (even if newVal is declared globally).  Is there anyway that I can get hold of the newVal variable outside of the function so that I can use it to create my 2nd chart?  newVal is simply the y axis position of the draggable plotline. I'm afraid I'm not sure how to set up js fiddle to show you more

Comment: My 1st chart is similar to this one http://jsfiddle.net/48awM/ but with a horizontal plotline.

Comment: Ok see the using of global variable which is also a start value. http://jsfiddle.net/48awM/3/

Comment: I've updated the js fiddle to see if the global variable changes after the function: http://jsfiddle.net/48awM/5/.  If you drag the line you'll see that the global variable doesn't change after the function although the draggable plotline is working correctly. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: It doesnt work, bceause you print variable at the beginning, but you not call  ($("#report_after").text("After: " + globalValue);) and after aciton like stop, you dont call $("#report_after").text("After: " + globalValue); again, only single one at the beginning. So it works properly.

Answer (score 0):

Just increase its scope:

```
var line,
    clickX,
    clickY,
    newVal;

var start= function (e) {
    $(document).bind({
        'mousemove.line': step,
        'mouseup.line': stop
    });
    clickY=e.pageY - line.translateY;
}

var step = function (e) {
    line.translate(e.pageX - clickX, e.pageY - clickY)
}

var stop = function (e) {
    var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
    var max_y_axis = chart.yAxis[0].max;
    newVal = chart.yAxis[0].toValue(e.pageY - clickY + chart.plotTop) + chart.yAxis[0].plotLinesAndBands[0].options.value)- max_y_axis;
    $('#report').text('Value: ' + newVal);
    $(document).unbind('.line');
}
```

Comment: I've tried declaring newVal outside of the function at the top as you suggest. But the variable comes up as being undefined outside (and below) the function (it is defined correctly within the function). I'm not sure why this would be.  Do you have any ideas of how to fix this or another work around?  Thanks!